# Ordenar foreach em php

Tags: php, classificação, foreach

Fiz uma página que mostra o hash em vários hash_algos a fim de estudo de suas diferenças, porém eu gostaria de ordenar por o tamanho do hash e não por o nome do hash_algos, o código é este,

```
<?php foreach (hash_algos() as $hash_algos) {
        $hash = hash($hash_algos, "salt", false); ?>
        <li>
            <span><?php echo $hash_algos; ?></span>
            <span><?php echo strlen($hash); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo $hash; ?></span>
        </li>
<?php } ?>
```

teria como ao ser impresso, ser ordenado por o tamanho do hash que no caso dependendo do algos ele terá de 8 até 128 e fazer um sub sort com o algos, ou seja, colocar todos os de 8 com todos os fnv, o segundo sort não é tão importante, só queria mesmo ver como ordenar o que indica o tamanho.

exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/2KGIUw)

Grato desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria o caso de primeiro coletar os dados, e ordenar ao exibir:

```
   // Primeiro coletamos os resultados em $results

   foreach (hash_algos() as $hash_algos) {
      $hash = hash($hash_algos, "salt", false);
      $results[] = ['algo' => $hash_algos, 'len' => strlen($hash), 'hash' => $hash];
   }

   // Em seguida usamos usort($array, 'funcao') para ordenar com uma função própria

   function compara($a, $b) {
      return $a['len'] - $b['len'];
   }
   usort($results, 'compara');

   // finalmente exibimos o resultado final, já ordenado

   foreach ($results as $result) {
      echo $result['algo'].' '.$result['len'].' '.$result['hash'].PHP_EOL;
   }
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Sfsudd)**.

Entenda melhor o `usort()` no manual do PHP:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php

Comment: perfeito, muito bacana, eu vi em muitos locais que precisava criar outra function mas não estava entendendo como fazer, este PHP_EOL no final serve para o que mesmo?

Comment: corrija se estiver errado, é para fazer a quebra de linha?

Comment: @flourigh é só pra quebrar as linhas no demo (equivale ao "\n" ou "\r\n" do sistema operacional, no seu caso basta acertar o HTML). O importante mesmo é entender a função `usort`

Comment: sim, ele dentro da função irá ver quem é maior e o colocar na fila a cima ou a baixo para comparar com o próximo, não tive interação com ele ainda antes de você me mostrar, muito bom.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode também usar o `arsort`:

```
$algos = array_flip(hash_algos());

foreach($algos as $algo => $len){
      $algos[$algo] = strlen(hash($algo, '', true));
}

arsort($algos);

foreach($algos as $algo => $len){
    echo $algo . ' => ' .$len;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Lembrando que usar o `false` no último parâmetro do `hash`, como usado na sua pergunta, vai retornar o tamanho da hash em HEX. O hexadecimal é que o dobro do comprimento original.

Um SHA-512 tem exatos 512 bits, mas codificado para hexadecimal utilizará 1024 bits para armazenar 512 bits. Já usando Base64 os mesmos 512 bits passariam para 704 bits, para comparação. Então, acredito que o que deseja é o comprimento original e não em hexadecimal, *até porque você pode não usar hexadecimal*.

Comment: hum, muito bom mesmo, vou comparar os dois, mas gostei muito do seu também